# Why can't you reverse the order of the input redirection operator for while loops?

Tags: bash, io-redirection, syntax

In Bash you can move input redirection operators to the front of a command:

```bsh
cat <<< "hello"
# equivalent to
<<< "hello" cat
```

Why are you unable to do the same for while loops?

```bsh
while read -r line; do echo "$line"; done <<< "hello"
# hello

<<< "hello" while read -r line; do echo "$line"; done
# -bash: syntax error near unexpected token `do'
```

I find it a bit confusing since you *can* pipe into a while loop. Am I doing something wrong or was it just a design decision?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's just a consequence of how the grammar is defined. From [the POSIX Shell Grammar specification](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_10):

```
command          : simple_command
                 | compound_command
                 | compound_command redirect_list
                 | function_definition
                 ;
```

And:

```
simple_command   : cmd_prefix cmd_word cmd_suffix
                 | cmd_prefix cmd_word
                 | cmd_prefix
                 | cmd_name cmd_suffix
                 | cmd_name
                 ;
[...]
cmd_prefix       :            io_redirect
                 | cmd_prefix io_redirect
                 |            ASSIGNMENT_WORD
                 | cmd_prefix ASSIGNMENT_WORD
                 ;
cmd_suffix       :            io_redirect
                 | cmd_suffix io_redirect
                 |            WORD
                 | cmd_suffix WORD
                 ;
```

As you can see, with compound commands, redirection is only allowed *after*, but with simple commands, it is allowed before as well. So, when the shell sees `<redirection> foo`, `foo` is treated as a simple command, not a compound command, and `while` is no longer treated as a keyword:

```
$ < foo while
bash: while: command not found
```

Hence, the `do` is unexpected, since it's only allowed after certain keywords.

So this applies not just to `while` loops, but most of the ways of setting up compound commands using reserved words:

```
$ < foo {
bash: {: command not found
$ < foo if
bash: if: command not found
$ < foo for
bash: for: command not found
```

Comment: Nice explanation, thank you.